# How do I move a split pane to a new tab in iterm?

Tags: iterm2

This is doable in vim and tmux and most browsers.  How do I move a split pane into a new tab when in iterm2?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Hold <kbd>CMD</kbd>-<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>-<kbd>OPT</kbd> and drag the pane

- New Tab -> to the tab bar of a terminal window
- New Window -> away from the terminal window

Source: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/iterm2-discuss/kg_5b3EKCpM/c-pd3Bc_I-YJ

Comment: To go the other way, do the same. In some cases you have to drag the main view, others the title-bar.